# Why scan.next() + scan.nextLine() instead of scan.nextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What is the difference between:

```
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

and

```
String s2 = scan.next() + scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: what does the javadoc say?

Comment: Try it with `Scanner scan = new Scanner("hello world");`.

Comment: `next()` - returns the next token of the Scanner object. -> `"hello world" -> "hello"` ; `nextLine()` - returns the string the current line. -> `"hello world" -> "hello world"`

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about what both methods do. Please be specific and explain what still remains unclear.

Comment: `String s2 = scan.next() + scan.nextLine();` could be at some point considered as variant of `String s2 = scan.next(); scan.nextLine();` in which case you may be interested in [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reg. [Scanner javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

> `next()` - Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
>
> `nextLine()` - Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

So, with `next()` basically it reads only first word, only 1st token (string) is being taken (remaining things are stored in the buffer, but `nextLine()` allows you to read until enter is pressed= whole line.

Difference can be seen if you will try following snippet and try to put combinations of words and sentences:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("first input:");
String tmp = sc.next();
System.out.println("tmp: '" + tmp +"'");
System.out.println("second input:");
tmp = sc.next() + sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("2nd tmp: '" + tmp +"'");
}
```

Inputs and outputs:

```
first input:
firstWord
tmp: 'firstWord'
second input:
second sentence
2nd tmp: 'second sentence'
//-------------
first input:
first sentencemorewords
tmp: 'first'
second input:
2nd tmp: 'sentencemorewords'
```

Maybe better explanation comes with direct printing:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("first input:");
String tmp = sc.next();
System.out.println("tmp: '" + tmp +"'");
System.out.println("second input:");
System.out.println("next: " + sc.next() +",... nextLine: " + sc.nextLine());
```

> Notice, only first word is handled by first `sc.next()`, in case of more words any other word will be handled by second `sc.next()`, but in case of more than 2 words, remaining string will be handled by `nextLine`

```
first input:
first second third more words
tmp: 'first'
second input:
next: second,... nextLine:  third more words
```

> So in your program **if you need only one word, use `sc.next()`, if you need to read the whole line, use `nextLine()`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scanner.nextLine();
    String s2 = scanner.next()+ scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("scanner.nextLine(): "+ s); 
    System.out.println("scanner.next()+ scanner.nextLine(): " + s2);
```

Input + Output:

```
//Input
hello <enter pressed here>
world <enter pressed here>
//Output
scanner.nextLine(): hello
scanner.next()+ scanner.nextLine(): world
```

**nextLine()** method uses buffered input to read in a String that the user has entered. Buffered input means that the user is allowed to backspace and change the String until the user hits the Enter key - in this case, this will return the first inputted number.The **next()** method finds and returns the next complete token from the scanner, i.e. in this case will return the last input value.